# Changing UIBarButton title shows ellipsis between old and new title

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

When I'm dynamically changing a title of UIBarButton ellipsis shortly during changing:

[image]

I've tried to change frame of rightBarButton (make it wider), but it was not helpful.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button's `possibleTitles` property to the set of possible titles when you setup the bar button item.

```
let btnDoneSave = ...
// Other setup
btnDoneSave.possibleTitles = [ "Done", "Save" ]
```

There should also be a place in Interface Builder for filling in the possible titles if you are creating the bar button item there.